# Deserialize type extending abstract class in GSON

Tags: json, gson, abstract-class

I want to serialize/deserialize an array of Objects that extend an abstract object using gson. To do this I made a TypeHierarchyAdapter like this:

```
    private static class BaseModelAdapter<T extends BaseModel> implements JsonSerializer<T>, JsonDeserializer<T>{

    private static final String MODEL_TYPE_PROPERTY = "MODEL_TYPE_PROPERTY";
    private static final String CHILDREN_PROPERTY = "children";
    private static final Gson gson = new Gson();

    @Override
    public T deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT, JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {
        if(!json.getAsJsonObject().has(MODEL_TYPE_PROPERTY)) {
            throw new JsonParseException("Couldn't find target class! \n" + json.toString());
        }
        final String className = json.getAsJsonObject().get(MODEL_TYPE_PROPERTY).getAsString();
        try {
            return (T) gson.fromJson(json, Class.forName(className));
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, e);
            throw new JsonParseException("Couldn't find target class!", e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public JsonElement serialize(T src, Type typeOfSrc, JsonSerializationContext context) {
        final JsonObject ret = gson.toJsonTree(src).getAsJsonObject();
        ret.add(CHILDREN_PROPERTY, context.serialize(src.getChildren()));
        ret.addProperty(MODEL_TYPE_PROPERTY, src.getClass().getName());
        return ret;
    }

}
```

This I use the adapter like this:

```
TypeToken<List<BaseModel>> typeToken = new TypeToken<List<BaseModel>>(){};
GsonBuilder builder = new GsonBuilder();
builder.registerTypeHierarchyAdapter(BaseModel.class, new BaseModelAdapter<BaseModel>());
builder.setPrettyPrinting();
Gson special = builder.create();
String json = special.toJson(featured); //Works!
List<BaseModel> baseModels = special.fromJson(json, typeToken.getType()); //Exception Thrown!
```

It works perfectly if I make BaseModel not abstract, which I suppose I could do for the sake of making this work. But I would much rather keep BaseModel abstract as it should be. The exception thrown says it can not invoke a no-args constructor which has never been a problem with gson before. Adding a no-args constructor to my BaseModel class does not fix the problem and it still says the same message. Is there anyway I can get this to work while keeping BaseModel abstract?

Comment: It is suggested to use TypeAdapters. "new applications should prefer TypeAdapter, whose streaming API is more efficient than this interface's tree API." You should better try TypeAdapters, I've never used JsonSerializer and JsonDeserializer. Maybe that will be your solution. https://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/JsonSerializer.html